# How to always update updated_at of model when associations are mutated

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model like:

```
class Company < AR
  has_many :locations
end

class Locations < AR
  has_many :stores
end

class Store < AR
  has_many :products
end
```

Is it possible to have the company.updated_at to be updated each time any of the associations are mutated?

e.g. if a product is updated, I want it to bubble up and updated the company.updated_at column.

Is this possible?

Along the same lines, can I hook into the event when the company.updated_at is updated so I can make a redis call?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible you need to do like this:

```
class Company < AR
  has_many :products
end

class Product< AR
  belongs_to :company, touch: true
end
```

This will update the `updated_at` of `company` whenever there is change in the `products` which belong to that `company`.

And whenever the `company` is updated the `updated_at` will update so will `before_update` or `after_update` callback work for you? In which you can call redis.

More information [Touch](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/touch)

Comment: I can't say the exact number but yes it can go deep if you use it correctly.